# Highcharts : Info about clicked legend item pass to controller

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I have highcharts angular service with this option: I would like to know if is  somehow possible to pass information about visibility of clicked item to my controller. So I can for example store it in `$scope` variable. For example in my contorller (in which I call this service) I have variable `$scope.legendItemVisibility = null;` and I want store true or false value from legend.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        marker: {
            enabled: false,
            symbol: 'circle',
            radius: 2
        },
        events: {
            legendItemClick: function() {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution for that is by adding the reference to specific component, directly within `Chart` object. I did that by this way:

*app.component.html*

```
<highcharts-chart 
  [Highcharts]="Highcharts"

  [constructorType]="chartConstructor"
  [options]="chartOptions"

  (chartInstance)="addComponentRef($event)"

  style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;"
></highcharts-chart>
```

*app.component.ts*

```
export class AppComponent {

  Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chart: any
  legendItemVisibility: boolean = true

  addComponentRef(chart: any) {
    chart.parentComponent = this
  }

  chartOptions = {
    series: [{
      data: [1,2,3],
      events: {
        legendItemClick() {
          let component = this.chart.parentComponent
          component.legendItemVisibility = !component.legendItemVisibility
        }
      }
    }]
  };
}
```

**Live example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-cloning-chart-wtxk6g